# Splitting an array into equal sized chunks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a Google Sheet that lets you enter the number of pages in each chapter of a book like so:

```
Chapter | # of pages
5       | 75
6       | 88
...     | ...
53      | 63
```

And split it into x number of chunks of chapters,  so that each chunk has about the same number of pages. So say I want to read 300 pages in the next 5 days, and in the next 300 pages are a total of 13 chapters, each of varying length. How can I break those 13 chapters up so I have about the same amount of reading each day?

Edit:
![example of working sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7lbu.jpg

The goal is to enter an arbitrary number of chapters and days (in this case, 7) and distribute the chapters between the days so that there's an approximately even amount of pages per day, while keeping the chapters in order.

Comment: kinda unclear what exactly you want to split. share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268711/how-to-split-a-google-sheet-range-into-parts-by-sum/62271008#62271008

Comment: first you will have to define "about the same number of pages" since having to read 35 pages on day 2 is practically half as much as having to read 69 pages on day 7.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=TEXT(((C1*C3)/TEXT(C2, "[m]"))/24, "[h] \da\y(\s) m \min")
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. The time it takes to read each chapter and the actual number of chapters aren't as important as the number of pages read per day. I just don't know how to split up the chapters into blocks of approximately equal page length.